# Syntax error in my SQL when inserting a JSON field

Tags: sql

Why this query is not working:

```
UPDATE country SET timezones="[{"zoneName":'Asia\/Kabul',"gmtOffset":16200,"gmtOffsetName":'UTC+04:30',"abbreviation":'AFT',"tzName":'Afghanistan Time'}] " where name='Afghanistan'
```

Error I get:

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "zoneName"
LINE 1: UPDATE country SET timezones="[{"zoneName":'Asia/Kabul',"gm...
^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 34

Comment: SQL string literals are marked with single quotes, JSON string literals are marked with double quotes... `'[{"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"}, {etc...}]'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue with your SQL statement is that the literal string you are trying to set timezones to contains improperly formatted [escape characters](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-literals.html). if you wanted to avoid that first error you can double up on quotes like `timezones="[{""zoneName"":` ...

you can go to the link to see more about string formating in SQL. good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to update the value wrapping the string in quotes. You need to wrap the string in single quotes `timezones='[{"zoneName":'Asia...}]'`

However, to TitledTeapot's point, you will also have to escape the existing single quotes in your string, so you'd end up with something like this:

```
'[{"zoneName":''Asia\/Kabul'',"gmtOffset":16200,"gmtOffsetName":''UTC+04:30'',"abbreviation":''AFT'',"tzName":''Afghanistan Time''}]'
```